Consumer function in NestJS + @ssut/nestjs-sqs on Lambda server not working
I have been building the NestJS application for sqs service trigger which hosting on Lambda (I'm new on AWS platform). The app create queue by calling an endpoint with producer function implemented. It work properly on my local, but when it is on lambda server it is not trigger my consumer function. I have no clue for it since there is no error in the log.
Here is what have I checked:

The secret env from AWS is existed

Permissions on Lambda: AWSLambdaExecute, AWSLambdaSQSQueueExecutionRole, AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole, AmazonSQSFullAccess

Consumer module:


import { Module } from "@nestjs/common"
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config"
import { SqsModule } from "@ssut/nestjs-sqs"
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk"
import { config } from "@/configs"

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    SqsModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        AWS.config.update({
          region: config.AWS_REGION,
          accessKeyId: config.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
          secretAccessKey: config.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        })

        return {
          consumers: [
            {
              name: sqsQueueName,
              queueUrl: sqsUrl
            },
          ],
          producers: [
            {
              name: sqsQueueName,
              queueUrl: sqsUrl
            },
          ],
        }
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [ConsumersService],
  exports: [ConsumersService],
})
export class ConsumersModule {}



Consumer service:

import { Injectable, InternalServerErrorException, Logger } from "@nestjs/common"
import * as AWS from "@aws-sdk/client-sqs"
import { SqsConsumerEventHandler, SqsMessageHandler } from "@ssut/nestjs-sqs"

@Injectable()
export class ConsumersService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger("Consumer Service")

  constructor() {}

  @SqsMessageHandler(process.env.AWS_SQS_QUEUE_NAME, false)
  async handleMessage(message: AWS.Message) {
    const messageBody = JSON.parse(message.Body) as MessageBody

    this.logger.log("consumer message body:", messageBody)
  }

  @SqsConsumerEventHandler(process.env.AWS_SQS_QUEUE_NAME, "error")
  public onError(error: Error, message: AWS.Message) {
    this.logger.error("consumer error:")
    this.logger.error(error.toString(), JSON.stringify(message))
  }

  @SqsConsumerEventHandler(process.env.AWS_SQS_QUEUE_NAME, "processing_error")
  async onProcessingError(error: Error, message: AWS.Message) {
    this.logger.error("consumer processing error:")
    this.logger.error(error.toString(), JSON.stringify(message))
  }

  @SqsConsumerEventHandler(process.env.AWS_SQS_QUEUE_NAME, "timeout_error")
  public onTimeoutError(error: Error, message: AWS.Message) {
    this.logger.error("consumer timeout error:")
    this.logger.error(error.toString(), JSON.stringify(message))
  }
}



Serverless.yml

service: my-serverless

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs20.x
  region: <MY_REGION>
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - sqs:SendMessage
        - sqs:ReceiveMessage
        - sqs:DeleteMessage
      Resource:
        - arn:aws:sqs:<MY_REGION>:<MY_ID>:<MY_QUEUE_NAME>

functions:
  lambda:
    handler: dist/lambda.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: /
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: '{proxy+}'
      - sqs:
          arn: arn:aws:sqs:<MY_REGION>:<MY_ID>:<MY_QUEUE_NAME>
          batchSize: 1

resources:
  Resources:
    SqsQueue:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        QueueName: <MY_QUEUE_NAME>

custom:
  serverless-offline:
    noPrependStageInUrl: true
  dotenv:
    path: src/configs

I don't really have an idea why it do trigger on local, but not on the Lambda server. Did I missing something?
